# How to align a text with background-color?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

first time posting in the forum.
I'm a beginner in programming and currently learning web development.
I stumbled upon this problem while trying to re-create Google homepage.

This is the navigation bar that I am trying to fix.

[image: This is the navigation bar that I am trying to fix.]

The sign-up list was aligned properly earlier, but, when I add the background-color. It goes out of the alignment. How is it exactly to make it aligned with the rest of navbar elements?

html:

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="about">About</li>
    <li class="store">Store</li>
    <li class="gmail">Gmail</li>
    <li class="images">Images</li>
    <li class="btn">Sign in</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: add the same padding to all the elements

Comment: Put the complete code that makes your navbar look like this in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the `btn` class has different properties compared to all the other li classes. What you need to do in this case is to give to the container `header` some directives on how to align all the children. Assign a class to the header and style it.

```
.headerClass {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center; /* This will align vertically in the center all the children elements */
   padding: 20px 0; /* Give a bit of padding to make the button breath */
}
```

Then I would advise not to style every single li element with a class but just style them all with the properties they will have in common like:

```
.headerClass ul li /* This will style only the li elements inside the header */
     width: 100%;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center; /* this will horizontally center all the elements inside the li */
}
```

Then, if you need to add a button in the last list item, just write your html like that.

```
<header class="headerClass">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#>About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>Gmail</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><button class="btn">Sign In</button></a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

From an HTML perspective, list items are not interactive elements, so you don't need to write any text into them, they are just a container for your links, buttons etc. Basically when clicking on "About" for example, you are clicking on the link so it is correct that you write it into an `a` tag.

If you want to style all the links in your unordered list, you can do it like that:

```
.headerClass ul li a {
    color: red;
}

.headerClass ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the rest of the code, especially for the `ul` container. If `ul` doesn't have any CSS of its own, make the `li`s inline-blocks as shown below. Then all `li` elements will align at their (text) baseline by default:

```css
ul.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="about">About</li>
    <li class="store">Store</li>
    <li class="gmail">Gmail</li>
    <li class="images">Images</li>
    <li class="btn">Sign in</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

If the `ul` is a flex container, add `align-items: baseline;` to the flex container (i.e. the `ul`):

```css
ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
ul.menu li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="about">About</li>
    <li class="store">Store</li>
    <li class="gmail">Gmail</li>
    <li class="images">Images</li>
    <li class="btn">Sign in</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.btn{ 
  background-color: #1a73e8;
  color: white;
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 7px 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="store" href="#store">Store</a></li>
  <li><a class="gmail" href="#gmail">Gmail</a></li>
  <li><a class="images" href="#images">Images</a></li>
  <li><a class="btn" href="#btn">Sign in</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.